# PHP - Capturing the $_GET method safely

Tags: php, database, pdo, get

I've recently begun learning PHP and PDO. The long-term goal is the to be able to dynamically display content on a single `details.php` page from a database, using the `$_GET` method to capture the `?page=id` or some sort of variation.

In order to compare the `?page=id` my plan was to save this to a variable (`$pageId` or something) and compare that variable to a record in the database. If the record exists, grab that record, but I'm getting a little hung up on the prepared statement bit.

When I grab the `?page=id` with the get method, I would use a prepared statement to begin the query, but should I be doing anything to sanitize the content I'm logging before processing the query?

Comment: `$_GET` is a variable, not a method. There are thousands of tutorials out there showing how to do a prepared statement. The answer to the only question I see is "that depends." For security purposes, the prepared statement will protect you from any malicious values and no "sanitization" is needed. For business logic purposes, who knows?

Answer (score 1):

When using a PDO prepared statement to bind values or variables from user input, you don't **need** to sanitize the input (to prevent SQL injection in queries). However, it is better to restrict its content as far as possible.

For instance, assume the `id` input will be an integer number, you could use:

```
$getId = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php

Now you're sure it's an integer.

Futhermore you could restrict it to a valid integer, with something like:

```
if (($getId > 0) && ($getId < PHP_INT_MAX)) {
   .... proceed ....
}
```

In other words, *always restrict user input as much as possible*.

Comment: I would not count on filter_input solely.  `echo filter_var('2plus2is4', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);` gives `224` and I doubt that `filter_input()` behaves differently (but haven't checked that to be honest). IMO at least checking `is_numeric()`, `is_int()` before `filter_input()` is required.

Comment: @Jimmix Although, what you say, makes some sense, in the end it doesn't. I really don't care whether the valid integer 224 came from parameter value `2plus2is4` or from `224`. It really doesn't matter. As long as 224 is valid, I'm OK with it.

Answer (score -1):

You can use php sanitize functions to sanitize any data that comes with GET parameter.
For example your $_GET value equals to 123 and you want to filter and sanitize it.
Use:

`$number = $_GET['number'];
filter_var($number, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);`

or you can check if value that comes from $_GET is a number and > 0 by:

```
$number = $_GET['number'];
if(is_int($number) && $number > 0) {
  //start to check with database.
}
```

Comment: While not wrong (I didn't downvote), this answer is incomplete. Please see the answer by @KIKOSoftware

Answer (score -1):

See [sanitize functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php). Keep in mind that if you save any user passed information to log and then display it (ie by using administration panel) in browser, someone may pass you malicious javascript that your browser will execute. And if the browser is logged into the admin panel this can lead to security problem.

If you are asking such questions I would direct you also go [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10-2017_Top_10) to become familiar with other security risks.

Also google difference between Sanitization and Validation.

Some filter functions you may find useful are [here](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php) but don't rely on them only. For example a valid `id` number passing filter function may be `1`, `2`, `3` but also `1e5` which is a valid in terms of being number but not for the `id` in case of row `id` usually. The other thing is that some numbers may use `.` for separation of decimal but others use `,` and both are valid depending on the country and financial interpretation of these signs. In some counties `.` is a thousand separator so `1k` = `1.000`.
That's why you should be not relaying 100% on filter functions but treat them as a part of your own functions.